# Ubuntu 19.10 space issue

Tags: 19.10

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04, I started noticing unusual writes to my hard disk. Something was writing to my hard disk and I ran out of space. I managed to clear some space but then I noticed on system monitor that I was loosing MBs by the second and please note that this happened after upgrading to 19.10. There was no issues with the upgrade process, it completed successfully.

I hope someone can help me urgently as I use this computer as my daily driver.

Please see screenshot below,

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're getting a lot of log writes. 20M/s! Check your syslog -- `journalctl`

Comment: How do I check syslog? 

I had more than 180 GB free and now down to 65 GB and loosing by the minutes...surely it's a bug with the 19.10 system?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `journalctl -r` This will list your logs with latest write first. Once you solve the problem you'll be able to clear the logs and get your space back. Probably some silly little thing.

Comment: Thanks for that. Cleared the logs but still loosing space :( 
Something keeps writing and filling up the space.

Comment: What is the log saying? It is writing something with unusual frequency. Something is cycling on an issue so you must identify that issue and address it. So: what is the log saying?

Comment: Do `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and watch what appears. It's probably something that's repeating itself.

Comment: I think I cleared the logs using Stacer. Looking at the log doesn't make any sense to me. 

Please see here, https://i.ibb.co/sms0CHL/image.png

Comment: @heynnema Thank you, the output is going crazy, please see here, https://i.ibb.co/23wGxTT/image.png

Comment: Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: See https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6586/daemon-shuts-down-on-startup-mdb-bad-txn-transaction-must-abort-has-a-child The problem is in your cyptocurrency app/database.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will do the file system check and post back. 

In regards to the Cryptocurrency app/database, I don't use Cryptocurrency ?

Comment: Make sure to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them. Do the fsck. Is it possible that somebody else installed Monero? Or you've been hacked? `ps auxc | grep -i monero`.

Comment: Also see https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8350744.html?sid=b309310a4ac127c65899dec88eb28daa

Comment: @heynnema sorry I forgot to tag you before.

Surely, it would have been a problem with 19.04 too if I was hacked or whether that Monero program was installed but it all started after the 19.10 upgrade. Very strange!

Comment: @heynnema, I had to go out so, once I get home, I will check the disk for errors and report back. Also, I will look at the fixes suggested in those links that you posted.

Comment: @heynnema, running this command did nothing, 

ps auxc | grep -i monero

Comment: @heynnema monero didn't exist on my system but following those links that you posted helped me sort my issue. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope the steps below will help someone if they ever come across a similar issue.

Thank you very much to @heynnema and the users above who helped.

Here is what finally fixed the issue,

1. Ran these 2 commands to monitor the log files,

journalctl -r

tail -f /var/log/syslog

2. The log files pointed to an output similar to the output below,

org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid

3. Disabled Baloo File Indexing using the command below, and my CPU processes and writing to the hard disk stopped immediately

balooctl disable

4. My syslog file was over 250GB and so I cleared it by login in as root on terminal (re commands below)

Syslog file location on Ubuntu (~/var/log/syslog)
Login as root on terminal using the command `su -`
Then run the command `> /var/log/syslog` this clears the log file

5. Just to be safe I checked the file systems for any errors using the commands below as @heynnema suggested

> Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live
>   DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
>   Type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

I had no errors on my file system so all good now.